# GDB "start" command fails with "Cannot insert breakpoint 1" and "Cannot access memory at address"

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, ubuntu-18.04

First build a trivial program:

```
g++ -g -xc++ - <<< 'int main() {throw "hi";}'
```

This produces `a.out` which intentionally crashes when run.  Try to debug it:

```
gdb -batch -ex start -ex continue ./a.out
```

The expected output is something like this:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at <stdin>:1
1   <stdin>: No such file or directory.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff71ad1f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

But on Ubuntu 18.04 (which has GDB 8.1), a warning is printed and the `start` command fails:

```
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x4005c7

Command aborted.
```

How can I tell GDB to stop my program at the very beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDB 8.1 added a new `starti` command which works around this problem.  This stops the program at the first instruction, as opposed to `start` which sets a breakpoint on `main()` but doesn't work anymore.